# Do multiple insert into tables from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have following classes

```
class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_one :tableb
end
class TableB < < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :tableA
end
```

I have a tableA/form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@@table) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :tableAColumn %>
    <%= f.text_field :tableAColumn1 %>
    #how can i how this 
    <%= f.text_field :tableBColumn %>
    <%=f.text_field :tableBColumn1 %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<%end>
```

So that when i click on save both the records can be saved in Table A and Table B.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used accepts_nested_attributes_for

[Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)